# Mistake during Aleinu

Tags: aleinu-leshabeiach

If a person messes up a word during Aleinu, can a person just say that line again? or do they have to say the entire Aleinu? same with the second paragraph. What if I said the first paragraph perfectly and I made a mistake during the second? do I just say the second paragraph again or do I have to say both again? It's stressing me out because I keep messing and I end up saying Aleinu a trillion times.

Comment: You don't have to repeat anything. Daily recitation of 'alenu is not a formal obligation, but just a customary addition. || If it is easier, you can just say it in English (as you can with most prayers).

Comment: Note that if by any chance there is a component of OCD, then even were 'alenu not merely a customary addition, it would be appropriate to just say the prayers once. See [this discussion](http://adderabbi.blogspot.com/2014/09/rav-asher-weiss-on-ocd.html) of a responsum by R. Asher Weiss about the topic.

Comment: By the wording of your final sentence, it sounds like this is a practical concern for you. We generally avoid practical Halacha on here and advocate seeing your Rabbi. You can find more information about this policy in the box on the right side of the home page.

Answer (score 1):

The Ailiyah Rabba o'c' 51'8' says that it seems from the poskim that in a case where one has got to repeat the possuk posaiach es yadecha in ashrei because of a lack in kavanah,one need not repeat from there until the end of ashrei but rather it is enough for him to repeat the possuk poseiach by itself.

His reasoning being that only in shema do we find that when repeating the first possuk one must as well say the entire parasha again as it is learnt out of vehaau which is specifically referring to shema.

The shulchan aruch however says that one needs to repeat from there and on,as it is a perek in tehilim which was written to be said as is, and when the chachomim said to say it it was in this manner only.

As we see even when saying pesukim it is debatable and surely all the more so when saying a paragraph not from pessukim it is not meakaiv to say it in that order specifically.

Therefore in our case it certainly will not be required to repeat it in its order.

Consider too,thatit not being a real chiuv to be said would also add to our leniency, as we find by hallel said on rosh chodesh that if one missed a word one need not go back,being that on rosh chodesh it is not a real chiuv to be said