# Oseh Shalom Amidah mistake

Tags: shemoneh-esrei

if a person accidentally slurred their words or made a mistake in the amidah on the part that says "He who makes peace in His heavens, may He make peace for us and for all Israel; and say, Amen.", do they have to recite the amidah again? or just that part?

Comment: That's not part of the Amidah.

Comment: see [here](http://etzion.org.il/en/concluding-shemoneh-esrei) for an interesting analysis on the topic. This is not part of shmonei esrei but since the Gemara mandates saying goodbye properly, I think you need to repeat just the sentence. For sure not the whole amida.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/87003/mistake-during-aleinu#comment277478_87003.

Comment: I don't think there's a single part of the amidah where slurring the words makes you repeat the whole thing.   For that matter, even if you say the wrong word you almost always don't have to repeat the whole thing.  As far as I know there's exactly one exception, המלך הקדוש, and even there if you catch it within 3 seconds you're fine.  Anyway please please please consider @mevaqesh's comment.